# Cannot move Webparts

Tags: sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I have a page in a sharepoint site. When it is edited (Site Actions -> Edit page), there are various webparts in different webpart zones available. I drag and drop some webparts from one webpart zone to another. This happens perfectly in some browsers (IE 9 Compatibility view) but this doesn't work in many of the browsers at all. 
It gets moved to a different zone, but doesn't retain that position when the page is published again.
I tried this in Chrome as well as firefox, IE9 (normal mode) but this doesn't work anywhere.
Is this a general issue with Sharepoint?
Does it have anything to do with webparts hosted in those pages?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've learned from a Microsoft employee, who demos SharePoint to clients in their Atlanta campus data center, enterprise support for cross browser compatibility didn't come along until SharePoint 2010.

Notice, that the Microsoft Communicator colored presence status also doesn't show up next to a username in non-IE browsers in MOSS 2007.  Also, Firefox has a terrible experience in the rich textbox field.